# What is difference between self.pool['res.partner'] and self.pool.get('res.partner')

Tags: python

**What is main  difference between following :**

```
self.pool['res.partner'].browse(cr, uid, partner_id, context=context)
```

and

```
self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, partner_id, context)
```

As per my understanding both returns single record of type res.partner if partner_id e.g. 1

Then why it is used like this.

Comment: is `self.pool` a dictionary?

Comment: Thanx anand for your corrections.

Answer (score 3):

if `self.pool` is a dictionary (I hope :) ) then `self.pool['res.partner']` will raise an exception (`KeyError`) if the 'res.partner' is not present in that dictionary.

`self.pool.get('res.partner')` in the same case will return default value (which is None).

If you want to specify a different default value, you can do it like that: `self.pool.get('res.partner',some_def_value)`.

Comment: Though I do not see any benefit of using `get` in the above case . Instead of `KeyError` it would end up in `AttributeError` , when trying to access `.browse` on `None` object.

Comment: That is a different issue. For example, one could provide some default object with the proper structure (e.g. default partner) if that's the intention.

Comment: @Ashalynd I want reason behind one uses dictionary and another uses get method. why?

Comment: Very difficult to say why a particular person does something. Normal logic suggests that one would use `get` if there is no guarantee that the given key exists in the dictionary and you don't want to process an exception, and use dictionary accessor method if either they are sure that the given key is present, or they prefer to process KeyError explicitly.